# Android Studio 4.0 new UI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

I've recently updated to Android Studio 4. There are some things I noticed that changed from the previous version. Does everyone have these changes or is there a way to go back to the old UI?

For example the "Select Icon" menu now looks like that:
[Select Icon UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsW3h.png)
It used to be way more organized.

Another example would be the "New Java Class" UI
[New Java Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3YdG.png)
I used to be able to extend classes directly while creating a new class.

Did you also get these changes?

Android Studio 4.0.1
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763, built on June 25, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 12
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.google.services.firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio 4.0.1 everyone has these changes in the UI

If you want to back to the old UI you can download a version older than 4.0.1 for example 3.6 from Android Studio Download Archive

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

and you can install it without redownloading SDK

but in my opinion, you should use the latest version because you may need to use MotionLayout any other feature in the future version